# SMS auto response application

Tags: codeigniter, mobile, laravel-4

I really don't know how to go about this project. I'm a web developer with skills on codeigniter and laravel...
I want to build a project. that user will just text an id number to a phone number. the system will take the id and query the database. then a response will be giving back to the user
Example 1999 to 33388 from the user phone

How do i go about building this project
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Twilio provides this functionality. You can integrate this with codeigniter. Check [this link](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries).

Comment: tanks very must @pritzzz, your answer is very helpful